# Memory stick not showing in My Computer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb, usb-flash-drive, device-manager

I'm using Windows 8 64 bit Pro edition. I have a Sony memory stick which isn't showing up in my computer section. If I open Device manager I can see the stick there named as a mass memory device. I tried updating the drivers, removing it through the device manager and changing the stick to another USB port. If I try to use the stick on another computer (not a Windows 8 machine though) it works just fine.

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you put memory stick in your notebook or using external card reader? is device manager Clean with no unknown device?

Comment: I've plugged it straight to my computer and no unknown devices are shown.